# CosmosDB C# SDK ProyUrl missing

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am working on a containerized micro-services project (docker) in .NET Core targeting Azure. So we are using Azure Cosmos DB, and the C# Cosmos DB SDK (v2.4 since v3 is only in preview) for the CoreSql Api.

During development, I am behind a proxy, so I need to specify the proxy url for everything going outside. It works fine with HttpClientHandler for any HttpClient.

Using Cosmos DB SDK, I however don't see how to set this up on my DocumentClient.

In the Azure Node SDK, I see I could just create a ConnectionPolicy and set the ProxyUrl property for this purpose:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/cosmos/connectionpolicy?view=azure-node-latest#proxyurl

However, in the C# variant, no ProxyUrl:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.connectionpolicy?view=azure-dotnet

Is there another way to set that?
It is a missing feature in Cosmos DB SDK?
Thanks!
Eric

Comment: After some experiences with MS cloud technologies I would recommend writing Your own rest client. C++/Go client Api is usually extremely buggy and if pricing matters to You their libraries do best for You to pay the most (prime example being service bus over APMQ where their client library establishes connection for each request which greatly affects pricing) You might have some luck opening ticket if you have premium support on hand.

Comment: Are you passing the HttpMessageHandler on the DocumentClient constructor? https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/434#issuecomment-445594004

Comment: Thanks Matias, this is what I was looking for!
It works now and my docker container get access to my CosmosDB collection!

So in C#, adding the HttpMessageHandler is the alternative to the ProxyUrl in JS

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting in the config file like below:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Alternatively ,you can use HttpMessageHandler class as mentioned by @Matias.

Answer (score 0):

When using the CosmosDbClient for C#, if on Core 2.2 (unsure about previous versions), you can pass an instance of WebProxy as part of CosmosClientOptions parameter.

example:

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://< yourproxy.com >:< port number >", true, new List< string >().ToArray(), new NetworkCredential { Domain = "< domain >", UserName = "< username >", Password = "< password >" });
```

and then

```
CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(< EndpointUri >, < PrimaryKey >, new CosmosClientOptions { ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway, WebProxy = proxy });
```

Note that when using a Proxy, you will be forced to use ConnectionMode as Gateway.